# Do I get the saving throw benefit of Mounted Combatant Feat as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

I have a gnome ranger beast master who uses his wolf companion as a mount. Now the feat allows the mount to receive no damage on a successful dex saving throw instead of taking half in case they are subjected to an area effect that allows such a save.

Does this mean if the gnome is riding the wolf when such a check is required (like a fire breath or an explosion) then the gnome can arguably be considered to have succeeded the check too and also receive no damage?

Come to think of it... I think my question applies not just to my gnome, but also to anyone riding a regular mount

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**AOE attacks hit everyone in the attack zone as a separate attack.**

> **Mounted Combatant:** You are a dangerous foe to face while mounted. While
>   you are mounted and aren’t incapacitated, you gain the
>   following benefits:
>
> • You have advantage on melee attack rolls against any
>   unmounted creature that is smaller than your mount.
>
> • You can force an attack targeted at your mount to target
>   you instead.
>
> • If your mount is subjected to an effect that allows it to
>   make a Dexterity saving throw to take only half damage,
>   it instead takes no damage if it succeeds on the
>   saving throw, and only half damage if it fails.

IF you and your mount are occupying the same square (such as when you are riding the mount) you also are targeted by the AOE attack.  The ability for your mount to receive no damage on a DEX save is meant to keep your mount up and in fighting condition. No where does it state that you yourself receive this benefit as well.